# How to get the name of a File that is in a Scanner Object in java?

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

Hello:
I was given a Scanner that is a File. Something like this:

```
Scanner theScan = new Scanner(new File("name.file"));
```

I was wondering if there is a way to get the name of the file from the Scanner object.
I tried:

```
theScan.getName();
```

but that just works for File objects.
Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first thing the `Scanner(File)` constructor does is to call another constructor, like this:

```
this((ReadableByteChannel)(new FileInputStream(source).getChannel()));
```

so once the scanner has been constructed, there is no way to recover which file, and thus which filename, a scanner is reading from.

You'll simply have to keep track of this yourself on the outside. You could for instance encapsulate this into a `FileScanner` which extends `Scanner` but saves the file used when constructing it in a field.

Answer (score 0):

> #### API is your friend
>
> A scanner can read text from any object which
> implements the Readable interface. If
> an invocation of the underlying
> readable's
> Readable.read(java.nio.CharBuffer)
> method throws an IOException then the
> scanner assumes that the end of the
> input has been reached. The most
> recent IOException thrown by the
> underlying readable can be retrieved
> via the ioException() method.

For example, here are some of them:

```
    Scanner sc1 = new Scanner("some string");
    Scanner sc2 = new Scanner(System.in);
```

It would not make any sense asking: from what file the input comes from.

#### Fix

Encapsulating `file` and `scanner` in the `Filescanner` instance. Example:

```
public static class FileScanner {
    private final Scanner _sc;
    private final File _file;
    public Scanner get_sc() {return _sc;}
    public File get_file() {return _file;}

    public FileScanner(File f) throws 
           FileNotFoundException, NullPointerException  {
        super();
        this._sc = new Scanner(f);
        this._file = f;
    }
}
```

In this case `FileScanner` is aware of the file existence. Don't forget to call    `fs.get_sc().close();`, when you are done using the scanner.